# Fast link to related tags and/or searches and/or man pages

Tags: feature-request

I saw someone mention in a FAQ something about dupe linking and how that can be a nice trail to other useful resources within the exchange.

Would be nice for more experienced users to be able to link directly from within an answer to related tags or searches within SO that may be useful to the OP.

An example would be a question about some function that in context isn't answered by other questions but have close relations to other questions.

It would be nice to have an autocomplete tag list that an answerer could use to add linked resources to their answer.

Like

```
php:tags
    searches
    man-pages
```

---

```
         |<- http://stackoverflow.com/filter/tags-for-index; filter=php ->|
php:tags:php        = [php](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php)
         cakephp    = [cakephp](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cakephp)
         phpmyadmin = [phpmyadmin](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/phpmyadmin)
         ...
```

---

```
php:searches:explode = [search php explode](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[php]+explode)
```

---

```
php:manual:language-reference
           security
           functions


php:manual:functions:e
                     echo    = [php echo](http://php.net/manual/en/function.echo.php)
                     explode = [php explode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php)
```

---

These are general examples and not really useful. It'd work better for more obscure subjects that may have tangentially related discussion.

I know there is a lot more to be considered (especially with the manual -- rights and parsing and mapping). But the internal stuff could be extremely useful.

Comment: Is there an alternative meaning to `man page` that I'm unaware of? Sounds like a dating service.

Comment: This is a nice idea. I've been thinking about a similar thing, but as a *standalone service* - a URL service that you link to like, say, `domain.com/php/file_get_contents` or `domain.com/javascript/window.open` and that forwards automatically to the correct canonical manual resource. But because the effort to build and especially maintain this would be *huge*, I doubt whether Stack Exchange will be willing to do this as a SE feature

Comment: @mikeTheLiar: `man` is a common command on Linux systems to access a manual page (or help documentation) for a given service.

Comment: @animuson Thanks for the clarification, I'm not really up on the *nix platforms.